# Dynamically added elements - using $(this)

Tags: coffeescript, jquery

When adding a element to the dom dynamically like this:

```
row = """
    <div class="ipad-row">
        <h3>Sample Row</h3>
        <div id="wrapper-placeholder">

            <div class="scrollView" style="">
                <a class="btn btn-primary add-row-item">Add an item</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
"""


$(".add-row").live "click", ->
    $(".ipad .body").append row
    false
```

How come when I try and get this from the a link inside that row element, I get window:

```
$(".add-row-item").live "click", =>
    f = $ this
    console.log f // this logs window object, not the link element?
    f.parent().append row_item
```

Can someone please explain this behavior and how i can use $(this) like you would if the element did exist when the dom loaded?

Thanks

Comment: `live()` is deprecated, you should use `on` instead.

Comment: Thanks, let me do that

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`=>` changes `this` to the `this` in the parent context:

```
$(".add-row-item").live "click", =>
    f = $(this)
```

compiles to

```
var _this = this;
$(".add-row-item").live("click", function() {
    var f = $(_this);
```

Use `->` instead, which won't modify `this`.

Comment: it's very unusual that a 78.3 k reputation guy is not saying anything about live()

Comment: @Ankit "Use `$(document).on('click', '.add-row-item', function() { ... });` instead of `.live`, because deprecated blabla - see docs for [`.on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/)". I answered the question, which is about Coffeescript syntax, not jQuery.